# Minecraft Crashing

Tags: minecraft-java-edition, technical-issues, graphics-card

I am facing a problem with Minecraft. It is actually crashing every time I start playing it. I am running Windows 10 64-bit on PC with an Intel Core i5 Processor (2nd Gen). [Here is a link to the error log](https://onedrive.live.com/redir?resid=F3845903B90C486C!3196&authkey=!AILD-HISc36LKyY&ithint=file%2Clog).

My graphics card broke, and this problem appeared afterward. So, is it happening because of the absence of a graphics card?

Thanks! :D

Comment: What's your CPU, is it by any chance Intel Core i3 i5 OR i7 ???

Comment: @ИвоНедев Intel Core i5 Processor 2nd Gen

Comment: And would you happen to have nay visual mods installed ? It is very possible that your PC can't handle Minecraft on the Integrated Graphics Card alone...

Comment: Also, this is not the full error log, and it tells you were to find the full report: C:\Users\Laddagiri1234\AppData\Roaming\.minecraft\hs_err_pid6708.log

Comment: @TrentHawkins thanks for telling me i have edited the question :)

Comment: I'm willing to bet it's because of the missing graphics card. Hopefully your new one will resolve the issue when it's delivered.

Comment: Your crash log states that it's actually running Windows 8.1. Be aware that 10 does not support the version you run on 7 and 8; it has it's own app version you need to install. Minecraft uses some.basic openGL. EVen the basic card should support it, and if that was broken, you wouldn't have output to your screen.

Answer (score -1):

By the [looks of it](http://www.minecraftforum.net/forums/support/modded-client-support/2385373-game-crashing-a-few-seconds-after-entering-a-world), and the information you gave, your Integrated GPU just can't handle Minecraft

One of the few things besides getting an actual GPU (hopefully you are on Desktop) is to try and update your Integrated Graphics Drivers trough [here](https://downloadcenter.intel.com/product/59134/2nd-Generation-Intel-Core-i5-Processors) (Intel HD Graphics Driver)

Also given comments and Rating of the Answer, please check OP's Integrated GPU compared to the minimum required GPU 
http://www.game-debate.com/gpu/index.php?gid=482&gid2=351&compare=intel-gma-3150-vs-mobility-radeon-hd-2400

OP's GPU is at least twice as bad!

Comment: Is it also because of the absence of the graphics card? I actually ordered my new graphics card online so it might be getting delivered in a few days.

Comment: Well that's why I asked if its a Core Ix processor. Core i3,5 and 7 has a bit that can do graphics, but is no way near as powerful as most dedicated GPUs. So even though your GPU broke, you can still turn your PC on and load into Windows etc. but can hardly run any games.

Comment: Actually i tried to install the drivers but unfortunately i don't have drivers suitable for windows 10 and intel core i5 2300 series. Anyways

Comment: @Bhavesh Windows 7, 8 and 8.1 is all the same in terms of Drivers. Get those that would work on 8.1 and you are good.

Comment: @JoeWallis You might as well +1 me. I don't recommend GMA to anyone ... Look OP's GPU compared to those from your link http://www.game-debate.com/gpu/index.php?gid=482&gid2=351&compare=intel-gma-3150-vs-mobility-radeon-hd-2400 I'm only talking about Video Card and not CPU, his CPU is powerful enough, his GPU is CRAP as the Processor is not really ment to also provide powerful graphics ...